# Kubuntu 22.04 freezes with second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, kde, freeze

#### Setup

Hey, I have Kubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (i7-11800H, Nvidia 3050Ti) for more than a year. I use two screens (laptop + external monitor).

#### Problems

Since around a month ago, following problems occur (I believe they are related but this is only an assumption):

- second monitor freezes randomly for ~5 sec
- second monitor sometimes (ca. every 3 hours; mostly after resume from suspend)  freezes completely; unplugging and replugging HDMI resolves problem
- An open Google Chrome window freezes always after resume from sleep for ~10 sec (this is reproducible) but system remains responsive

#### Things I did

- update to nvidia-535 driver and to noveau driver. Problem persists (I think I had nvidia-525 before, but I am not sure)
- disable Compositor effects; problem persists
- do `sudo prime-select intel` to disable gpu. Second monitor does not work with this setting and Chrome does not freeze after resume from sleep. However, Chrome freezes always on first launch for ~10 sec...

---

Has anyone of you had similar problems? And what might be promising steps to resolve this? Thank you!